# GitHub, creating new repository (Github API token)

Tags: python, api, oauth, github, token

I have written python scripts to list repositories and commits.
To create a new repository, I have used the following code:

```
curl -F 'login=SolomonPeter26' -F 'token=mygithubapitoken' https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/create -F 'name=REPONAME' -F 'description=This project is a test'
```

I can't access github API token of other users. So I couldn't write a python script for that sake.

Please suggest a better way to create such a new repository or a way to access the Github API token.( Can I get any help from oauth or oauth2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. You can't access API tokens of other users. It's same with twitter. You need to use Oauth2, and each user should get the API keys\tokens and add them manually in the code. What you can do is provide an easy way for your users to add github API token.

Answer (score 0):

I use Postman (a Chrome plug-ins). It can test success:
[image]

With the `access_token`, you can find personal access tokens of your account's setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic formula on [Ritchie CLI](https://ritchiecli.io) to create a Github repository, using the user's Github API token.

*Obs: The user will have to set the token manually the first time the command will be executed on the terminal (to save it locally).*

Here are the [code](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-github/blob/master/github/create/repo/src/formula/formula.py) and the [README file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-github/tree/master/github/create/repo) of this formula (in Python)

Here is an example of how it consumes the POST resource to create a repository with the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user):

```
authorization = f'token {token}'
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    "Authorization" : authorization,
    }

r = requests.post(
    url='https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    data=json_data,
    headers=headers
    )
```

As you can customize the commands using the tool, it is possible to automate many other operations with Github API the same way.